# How to select and show all the tickets from last calendar year?

Tags: select, date-format, firebird

It seems SQL calls varies a lot, and cannot find how to do this in Firebird, where SQL dialect is 3.

There's a table called TICKETS. This table has INSERT_TIME which is TIMESTAMP. How do I select all the tickets which has insert time year = 2016?

Comment: Doesn't YEAR(INSERT_TIME) work?

Comment: Dynamic SQL Error, SQL error code = -104, -Token unknown - line 1, column 31, -YEAR

Comment: extract(year from INSERT_TIME) https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-extract.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your needs, you can use:

1. Using [`extract`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-extract):

   ```
    select *
    from tickets
    where extract(year from insert_time) = 2016
   ```
2. Using [`between`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-predbetween):

   ```
    select *
    from tickets
    where insert_time between timestamp'2016-01-01 00:00:00.0' and timestamp'2016-12-31 23:59:59.99999'
   ```

Depending on the volume of data, and the presence of an index on `insert_time` or not, the second may be preferable over the first.